# (Why) Can we simply assume a given alignment of VEVs?

Tags: specific-reference, higgs, grand-unification

In GUT theories, one often assumes that Higgs fields take VEVs in given representations, of a given magnitude at a given scale.

While I am well aware that this is one of the weak spots in such theories, I suppose there must at least be some work into the possibilities of construcing a Higgs potential with a given VEV structure.

What works are there on Higgs potentials in GUT theories w.r.t. VEV structure?